# Autoit - How to get the current IE URL

Tags: internet-explorer, url, automation, autoit

I'm sort of new with Autoit and the software that i'm working on (IE) give new url every time user login to same page
for example:
"Constant page URL Bin_Listener.dll?CTX=REC!{91979FC1-E0DE-4EF4-A543-9312DD6D090E}&LOG&&&&&VMVEN=0"

Constant page URL Bin_Listener.dll?CTX=REC!{AABC1671-EA1C-4BEE-BE05-B680F2E18ECD}&LOG&&&&&VMVEN=0

as you can see the links are identical except the string under {}.
please advise,  how can I get the this page?
Thanks

Comment: Is this an IE instance that you are creating (with the IE.au3 library), or one that the user already has open?

Answer (score 3):

If IE is already open:

```
$oIE = _IEAttach("<Title of Page>")
$url = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
```

If not:

```
$oIE = _IECreate("<url>")
$url = _IEPropertyGet($oIE, "locationurl")
```